# Exponential map of a Formal Group Scheme

Tags: lie-algebras, group-schemes

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra over $k$. $\mathfrak{g}$ corresponds to a formal group scheme $\mathcal{G} = \text{Spf} (U(\mathfrak{g})^{*})$. In fact, there is an equivalence of categories between finite-dimensional Lie algebras and infinitesimal formal group schemes over $k$ with finite-dimensional tangent space. This is elaborated on [here](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/formal-lie-theory-in-characteristic-zero/) by Akhil Mathew.

There should be an exponential map $\text{exp} : \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$. This is mentioned at the end of the blog post above, but I can't figure out how to construct it explicitly.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You didn't specify that your field k has characteristic zero, but to get this equivalence, it is essential that your field k have characteristic zero. Part of the whole point of formal groups is that, over fields of positive characteristic, there are more formal groups than Lie algebras, so the formal group of an abelian variety remembers more structure than the Lie algebra!

Comment: Oh- that's right. I see I overlooked that requirement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}$
In a way this is tautological, in the sense that $\mathcal G$ can be seen as a formal exponentation of $\g$, although I don't think there is an actual exponential map from one to the other in general. Rather, there is a map (in fact an isomorphism of formal schemes) from the formal completion of $\g$ at the origin to $\mathcal G$.

Namely, the dual $U(\g)^*$ can be identified as a (topological) algebra with the algebra $\widehat S(\g^*)$ of formal power series on $\g^*$, ie with the formal completion of $\mathcal O(\g)$ w.r.t to the ideal of function vanishing at the origin.

This identification, should indeed be thought as pulling back functions through the exponential map: indeed, the induced coproduct on $\widehat S(\g^*)$ is expressed through the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula $$\forall x,y \in \g, \Delta(f)(x\otimes y)=f(BCH(x,y))$$ where BCH is the Lie formal power series defined on formal variables $a,b$ by 
$$BCH(a,b):=\log(e^ae^b).$$

Comment: Thanks. What is $S(-)$, here?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the symmetric/polynomial algebra.

Comment: If it's not too much extra, how do I make the identification between the space of formal exponentials and the space $\text{Spf} (U(\mathfrak{g})^*)$?

Comment: Sorry, that part was somewhat wrong, and the other confusing, I edited my answer. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Wait but $S(\mathfrak{g}^\vee)$ (the symmetric algebra on the vector space $\mathfrak{g}^\vee$) is always commutative and isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[[x_1,\ldots, x_n]]$ for some $n$, while the algebra $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ doesn't look commutative to me. So, probably I misunderstood the notation $S(\mathfrak{g}^\vee)$? [Edit: oh wait, but there's a dual $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})^\vee$, so first of all what's tha algebra structure on $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})^\vee$?]

Comment: Indeed, $U(\mathfrak g)$ is a cocommutative Hopf algebra, hence its full linear dual is a commutative, topological Hopf algebra, the multiplication being the transpose of the coproduct.

Comment: One last thing @Adrien, is there a reference where I could read about this? Specifically the identification of $\hat{S} (\mathfrak{g}^*)$ with $U(\mathfrak{g})^*$, and how this is done?

Comment: Or now I'm thinking we get a map $S(\mathfrak{g}) \rightarrow U(\mathfrak{g})$, which induces a map on their duals, and thus a map $U(\mathfrak{g})^* \rightarrow S(\mathfrak{g})^* \cong \hat{S}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$, but I'm not entirely certain if this is the identification being made.

Comment: Ah yes, $S(\mathfrak{g}) \rightarrow U(\mathfrak{g})$ is the symmetrization map! And hence the others are isomorphisms. Is this what you're saying?

Comment: Ah yes, sure, you use the Hopf alg. structure. And it is cocommutative. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @Dean: indeed, by PBW $U(\mathfrak g)\cong S(\mathfrak g)$ as coalgebras and it's a classical result that the pull back of the product of $U(\mathfrak g)$ through this iso can be expressed using BCH. Then it's an easy exercise that $S(\mathfrak g)^*=\widehat S(\mathfrak g^*)$.